# Use C++ Intellisense for custom ContentType

Tags: c#, visual-studio-extensions

I'm trying to make a simple extension with MEF for GLSL (It is also my first one, I tried to understand the language services and other stuff but I got completely lost. It seems like way too much work compared to MEF for a simple non-professional thing). I've been following the tutorials on MSDN and the OOK example to create basic syntax coloring, brace matching and IntelliSense support. I created my content type to extend C/C++, so I have the default coloring for C/C++ keywords, however I don't have access to C/C++ IntelliSense, the completion set isn't even in the list. Is there a way to get the default IntelliSense as well as my own completion set?

Here's my completion source:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Language.Intellisense;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Tagging;
using System.ComponentModel.Composition;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Utilities;

namespace GLSL_Extension {
    [Export(typeof(ICompletionSourceProvider))]
    [ContentType(GLSLConstants.ContentType)]
    [Name(GLSLConstants.CompletionSourceProviderName)]
    class GLSLCompletionSourceProvider : ICompletionSourceProvider {
        public ICompletionSource TryCreateCompletionSource(ITextBuffer textBuffer) {
            return new GLSLCompletionSource(textBuffer);
        }
    }

    class GLSLCompletionSource : ICompletionSource, IDisposable {
        private ITextBuffer buffer;
        private bool disposed = false;

        public GLSLCompletionSource(ITextBuffer buffer) {
            this.buffer = buffer;
        }

        public void AugmentCompletionSession(ICompletionSession session, IList<CompletionSet> completionSets) {
            if (this.disposed)
                throw new ObjectDisposedException(this.ToString());

            List<Completion> completions = new List<Completion>(){
                new Completion(GLSLCompletionResources.uniformName, GLSLCompletionResources.uniformName, GLSLCompletionResources.uniformDesc, null, ""),
                new Completion(GLSLCompletionResources.varyingName, GLSLCompletionResources.varyingName, GLSLCompletionResources.varyingDesc, null, ""),
                new Completion(GLSLCompletionResources.inName, GLSLCompletionResources.inName, GLSLCompletionResources.inDesc, null, ""),
                new Completion(GLSLCompletionResources.outName, GLSLCompletionResources.outName, GLSLCompletionResources.outDesc, null, ""),
                new Completion(GLSLCompletionResources.vec2Name, GLSLCompletionResources.vec2Name, GLSLCompletionResources.vec2Desc, null, ""),
                new Completion(GLSLCompletionResources.vec3Name, GLSLCompletionResources.vec3Name, GLSLCompletionResources.vec3Desc, null, ""),
                new Completion(GLSLCompletionResources.vec4Name, GLSLCompletionResources.vec4Name, GLSLCompletionResources.vec4Desc, null, ""),
                new Completion(GLSLCompletionResources.mat2Name, GLSLCompletionResources.mat2Name, GLSLCompletionResources.mat2Desc, null, ""),
                new Completion(GLSLCompletionResources.mat3Name, GLSLCompletionResources.mat3Name, GLSLCompletionResources.mat3Desc, null, ""),
                new Completion(GLSLCompletionResources.mat4Name, GLSLCompletionResources.mat4Name, GLSLCompletionResources.mat4Desc, null, "")
            };

            ITextSnapshot snapshot = this.buffer.CurrentSnapshot;
            var triggerPoint = (SnapshotPoint)session.GetTriggerPoint(snapshot);
            if (triggerPoint == null)
                return;

            var line = triggerPoint.GetContainingLine();
            SnapshotPoint start = triggerPoint;
            while (start > line.Start && !char.IsWhiteSpace((start - 1).GetChar())) {
                start -= 1;
            }

            var applicableTo = snapshot.CreateTrackingSpan(new SnapshotSpan(start, triggerPoint), SpanTrackingMode.EdgeInclusive);
            completionSets.Add(new CompletionSet("All", "All", applicableTo, completions, Enumerable.Empty<Completion>()));
        }

        public void Dispose() {
            if (!this.disposed) {
                GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
                this.disposed = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And my completion controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.ComponentModel.Composition;
using System.Diagnostics;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Language.Intellisense;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Editor;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextManager.Interop;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Utilities;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio;
using System.Windows;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace GLSL_Extension {
    [Export(typeof(IVsTextViewCreationListener))]
    [ContentType(GLSLConstants.ContentType)]
    [TextViewRole(PredefinedTextViewRoles.Interactive)]
    internal sealed class VsTextViewCreationListener : IVsTextViewCreationListener {
        [Import]
        IVsEditorAdaptersFactoryService AdaptersFactory = null;

        [Import]
        ICompletionBroker CompletionBroker = null;

        public void VsTextViewCreated(IVsTextView textViewAdapter) {
            IWpfTextView view = AdaptersFactory.GetWpfTextView(textViewAdapter);
            Debug.Assert(view != null);

            CommandFilter filter = new CommandFilter(view, CompletionBroker);
            IOleCommandTarget next;
            textViewAdapter.AddCommandFilter(filter, out next);
            filter.Next = next;
        }
    }

    internal sealed class CommandFilter : IOleCommandTarget {
        private ICompletionSession currentSession;

        public IWpfTextView TextView { get; private set; }
        public ICompletionBroker Broker { get; private set; }
        public IOleCommandTarget Next { get; set; }

        public CommandFilter(IWpfTextView textView, ICompletionBroker broker) {
            this.currentSession = null;
            TextView = textView;
            Broker = broker;
        }

        private char GetTypeChar(IntPtr pvaIn) {
            return (char)(ushort)Marshal.GetObjectForNativeVariant(pvaIn);
        }

        public int Exec(ref Guid pguidCmdGroup, uint nCmdID, uint nCmdexecopt, IntPtr pvaIn, IntPtr pvaOut) {
            bool handled = false;
            int hresult = VSConstants.S_OK;


            if (pguidCmdGroup == VSConstants.VSStd2K) {
                switch ((VSConstants.VSStd2KCmdID)nCmdID) {
                    case VSConstants.VSStd2KCmdID.AUTOCOMPLETE:
                    case VSConstants.VSStd2KCmdID.COMPLETEWORD:
                        handled = StartSession();
                        break;
                    case VSConstants.VSStd2KCmdID.RETURN:
                        handled = Complete(false);
                        break;
                    case VSConstants.VSStd2KCmdID.TAB:
                        handled = Complete(true);
                        break;
                    case VSConstants.VSStd2KCmdID.CANCEL:
                        handled = Cancel();
                        break;
                }
            }

            if (!handled)
                hresult = Next.Exec(pguidCmdGroup, nCmdID, nCmdexecopt, pvaIn, pvaOut);

            if (ErrorHandler.Succeeded(hresult)) {
                if (pguidCmdGroup == VSConstants.VSStd2K) {
                    switch ((VSConstants.VSStd2KCmdID)nCmdID) {
                        case VSConstants.VSStd2KCmdID.TYPECHAR:
                            char ch = GetTypeChar(pvaIn);
                            if (ch == ' ')
                                StartSession();
                            else if (this.currentSession != null)
                                Filter();
                            break;
                        case VSConstants.VSStd2KCmdID.BACKSPACE:
                            Filter();
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }

            return hresult;
        }

        private void Filter() {
            if (this.currentSession == null)
                return;

            this.currentSession.SelectedCompletionSet.SelectBestMatch();
            this.currentSession.SelectedCompletionSet.Recalculate();
        }

        bool Cancel() {
            if (this.currentSession == null)
                return false;

            this.currentSession.Dismiss();
            return true;


        }

        bool Complete(bool force) {
            if(this.currentSession == null)
                return false;

            if (!this.currentSession.SelectedCompletionSet.SelectionStatus.IsSelected && !force) {
                this.currentSession.Dismiss();
                return false;
            } else {
                this.currentSession.Commit();
                return true;
            }
        }

        bool StartSession() {
            if (this.currentSession != null)
                return false;

            SnapshotPoint caret = TextView.Caret.Position.BufferPosition;
            ITextSnapshot snapshot = caret.Snapshot;

            if (!Broker.IsCompletionActive(TextView))
                this.currentSession = Broker.CreateCompletionSession(TextView, snapshot.CreateTrackingPoint(caret, PointTrackingMode.Positive), true);
            else
                this.currentSession = Broker.GetSessions(TextView).First();

            this.currentSession.Dismissed += (sender, args) => this.currentSession = null;
            this.currentSession.Start();
            return true;
        }

        public int QueryStatus(ref Guid pguidCmdGroup, uint cCmds, OLECMD[] prgCmds, IntPtr pCmdText) {
            if (pguidCmdGroup == VSConstants.VSStd2K) {
                switch ((VSConstants.VSStd2KCmdID)prgCmds[0].cmdID) {
                    case VSConstants.VSStd2KCmdID.AUTOCOMPLETE:
                    case VSConstants.VSStd2KCmdID.COMPLETEWORD:
                        prgCmds[0].cmdf = (uint)OLECMDF.OLECMDF_ENABLED | (uint)OLECMDF.OLECMDF_SUPPORTED;
                        return VSConstants.S_OK;
                }
            }
            return Next.QueryStatus(pguidCmdGroup, cCmds, prgCmds, pCmdText);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to initialize the document model used by the C++ language services.  Decompile their code and see what services it yes.

Comment: @SLaks Decompile... Alright this look like a good Google session to me... Does that means I'll have to go through MPF with language services and all or is it still possible to access with MEF?

Comment: That depends on how the language services are written.  I think the C++ services are newer, but I have no idea how they work.

Comment: @SLaks I think this link gives some good infos on the subject: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/noahric/archive/2010/03/01/new-extension-css-is-less.aspx I might not need to find out how to decompile after all

Comment: The problem is that the C++ language service (unlike CSS) requires a project (for references, compilation settings, etc).  You will therefore need to work harder to make it work.

Comment: @SLaks I see... My guess is that I have to either create some sort of project type that extends the C++ one with the same editor factory, or try to make it work if the file is in a project (which is the most probable if we modify the shader at the same time as the rest of the app) and forget about loading it alone.

Comment: Or you could try to load the file into Miscellaneous Files (like VS does if you open a file without a project), which is basically a virtual project.  I'm not sure how easy that would be.